# For loop dataframe: how to print index names instead of number i and j?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a dataframe:

- Index of rows are all names of people.
- Index of columns are all ratings 1-10 on 7 different questions.

So, the dataframe consists of all numbers 1-10: A number for each question (column) for each person (row). It looks like this:

```
        Q1.    Q2.    Q3.   Q4.   Q5.   Q6.   Q7.     
Lotte   4      6      4     5     8     6      5
Lara    5      7      8     7     9     7      6
Linda   7      7      8     8     7     8      6
Tom     9      8      7     9     6     9      7
Jantje  9      9      9     10    7     10     8
```

Then I want to create a for loop through this data (called 'Score'), that checks every number. If the number is <5, I want to print: " For "NAME" for "QUESTION" it is lower than 5 ".

So, f.e: For Lotte for Q1 it is lower than 5.

I have the following code now:

```
for i in range(len(Score.columns)):
    for j in range(len(Score)):
        if Score.iloc[j,i] < 5:
            print ("Lower for %d" %i)
```

This only prints the column number, but I want to print the column and row, but named by the index. Can anyone help how to print this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite strightforward

you can use the dataframe method `iterrows` to iterate your rows, and then work on the single row to extract your knowledge. For completeness I generated an example dataframe to demonstrate the behaviour:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
# here I am generating my dataframe similiar to yours
list_of_dicts = [{'Q'+str(i)+'.':random.randrange(10) for i in range(1, 8)} for j in range(5)]
index = ['Lotte', 'Lara', 'Linda', 'Tom', 'jantje']

df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)
df.index = index

# here you can see the df structure 
print(df)

# here the algorithm
for row in df.iterrows():
  name = row[0]
  print("For " + name)
  for key in row[1].keys():
    if row[1][key] < 5:
      print("for {} it is Lower than 5".format(key))
```

My dataframe:

```
        Q1.  Q2.  Q3.  Q4.  Q5.  Q6.  Q7.
Lotte     6    8    5    8    8    1    6
Lara      1    7    0    7    5    5    1
Linda     6    6    0    3    9    7    4
Tom       5    8    2    5    3    8    3
jantje    5    5    9    9    5    0    3
```

My output:

```
For Lotte
for Q6. it is Lower than 5
For Lara
for Q1. it is Lower than 5
for Q3. it is Lower than 5
for Q7. it is Lower than 5
For Linda
for Q3. it is Lower than 5
for Q4. it is Lower than 5
for Q7. it is Lower than 5
For Tom
for Q3. it is Lower than 5
for Q5. it is Lower than 5
for Q7. it is Lower than 5
For jantje
for Q6. it is Lower than 5
for Q7. it is Lower than 5
```

Comment: Great thanks! Only one thing: I just want it to print when it is indeed lower than 5. I don't want it to print every name already, is there a way I can implement the names into the last print, after the if statement?

Comment: @Ja123 yes, you need to delete the first print, `print("For " + name)`, and print the full string as such `print("For {} for {} it is Lower than 5".format(name, key))`